# OpenGL vector graphics rendering performance on mobile devices

Tags: c++, ios, mobile, opengl-es, vector-graphics

It is generally advised not to use vector graphics in mobile games, or pre-rasterize them - for performance. Why is that? I though that OpenGL is at least as good at drawing lines / triangles as rendering images on screen...

Comment: Rasterizing them caches them so less overhead takes place vs calculating every coordinate for vector and drawing (more draw cycles and more cpu usage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rasterizing them caches them as images so less overhead takes place vs calculating every coordinate for vector and drawing (more draw cycles and more cpu usage). Drawing a vector is exactly that, you are drawing arcs from point to point on every single call vs displaying an image at a certain coordinate with a cached image file.

Comment: There are a lot of 3D games in App Store. They must be 10x more challenging to render than an average 2D vector-based game, but there are generally no performance problems! Am I wrong?

Comment: A 3d program generating 3d models is exactly that, yes. However, compare the performance of a 3d game to any 2d game and you'll see the difference. 3d games use raster graphics as their images for the objects so they are a hybrid of the 2. It comes down to a pre-rendered image vs creating one on the fly.

Comment: And I think you are misguided if you think there are no performance problems in 3d games. Talk to any 3d game developer and they will tell you optimization is EVERYTHING and should not be shrugged off as auto-magic. It's very hard to get a 3d game to perform well on a mobile device up until the past year and even then you limit quality vs quantity (frame-rate) in most cases for playability. The key thing to remember is everything is just a tool, use the correct tool for the job. If you require scalable graphics use SVG, if not, utilize the performance benefits of raster.

Comment: Thanks guys, now I think that I understand things a bit better. If I wanna draw something not much more complicated than an animated stickman (with ragdoll after his death) with support for many screen resolutions (Android devices, for example) vector graphics won't be as fast as raster, but will be acceptable? That's the last question and I'll accept.

Comment: In that situation you would actually want vector since you can easily manipulate things and support multiple resolutions. Scalability is the reason for SVG. Simple objects in SVG render extremely fast so the overhead by far outweighs the customization such as zooming all the way in on the rag dolls head without pixelation.

Comment: Take a look at cocos2D along with box2D or chipmunk (physics engines). They show why and how vector can be so powerful mixed with raster (sprites) since you can access specific points in a graphic for manipulation. Just like ragdoll blaster and others.

Comment: I'm already using box2d. After taking all arguments into consideration I think I won't use sprites, because my shapes are easy and managing multiple resolutions will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Although using impostors is a great optimization trick, depending on the impostors shape, how much overdraw is involved and whenever you may need blending in the process the trick can get you to be fillrate bound. Also in some scenarios where shapes may change, caching the graphics into impostors may not be feasible or may incur in other overheads. Is at matter of balancing your rendering pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the hardware. Are you using a GPU or NOT? 
Today modern mobile devices with Android and IOS have a GPU unit embedded in the chipset.
This GPUs are very good with vector graphics. To probe this point most GPU's have a dedicated Geometry processor in addition to 1 or more pixel processors. (By example Mali-400 GPU).
By example let's say you want to draw a 200 trasparent circles of different colors.
If you do it with modern OpenGL, you will only need one set of geometry (a list of triangles forming a circle) and a list of parameters for each circle, let's say position and color. If you provide this information to the GPU, it will draw it in parallel very quickly.

If you do it using different textures for each color, your program will be very heavy (in storage size) and probably will be more slow due memory bandwidth problems.

It depends on what you want to do, and the hardware. If your hardware doesn't have a GPU you probably should pre-render your graphics.